# SSRS Report Rpt File Top And Bottom Space Problem

Tags: reporting-services

[image: Image For Problem]

My Report File Fit To Page But Print Time Top and Bottom White Space Problem.

So Please My Help Solution.

[image: My Report File]

My Report File Is Ready But Not Proper Solved.

So Help Me.

Comment: Are you using a header? What size page is the report: letter or A4? It could be as simple as changing the page size.